# Really weird issue with shelve (python)

Tags: python, shelve

I create a file called `foo_module.py` containing the following code:

```
import shelve, whichdb, os

from foo_package.g import g

g.shelf = shelve.open("foo_path")
g.shelf.close() 

print whichdb.whichdb("foo_path")  # => dbhash
os.remove("foo_path")
```

Next to that file I create a directory called `foo_package` than contains an empty `__init__.py` file and a file called `g.py` that just contains:

```
class g:
    pass
```

Now when I run `foo_module.py` I get a weird error message:

`Exception TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable" in ignored`

But then, if I rename the directory from `foo_package` to `foo`, and change the import line in `foo_module.py`, I don't get any error. Wtf is going on here?

Running Python 2.6.4 on WinXP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you've hit a minor bug in 2.6.4's code related to the cleanup at end of program. If you run `python -v` you can see exactly at what point of the cleanup the error comes:

```
# cleanup[1] foo_package.g
Exception TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable" in  ignored
```

Python sets references to `None` during the cleanup at the end of program, and it looks like it's getting confused about the status of `g.shelf`.  As a workaround you could set `g.shelf = None` after the `close`.  I would also recommend opening a bug in Python's bug tracker!

Comment: The workaround works, thanks.  Here's the bug report:  http://bugs.python.org/issue7835

Answer (score 10):

After days of hair loss, I finally had success using an atexit function:

```
  import atexit
  ...
  cache = shelve.open(path)
  atexit.register(cache.close)
```

It's most appropriate to register right after opening. This works with multiple concurrent shelves.

(python 2.6.5 on lucid)

Comment: `2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34)`, the problem is still there; this (and only this) solution works

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed a Python bug, and I've posted a patch to the tracker issue you opened (thanks for doing that).

The problem is that shelve's **del** method calls its close method, but if the shelve module has already been through cleanup, the close method fails with the message you see.

You can avoid the message in your code by adding 'del g.shelf' after g.shelf.close.  As long as g.shelf is the only reference to the shelf, this will result in CPython calling the shelve's **del** method right away, before the interpreter cleanup phase, and thus avoid the error message.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an exception in a shutdown function registered by the `shelve` module.  The "ignored" part is from the shutdown system, and might get its wording improved sometime, per [Issue 6294](http://bugs.python.org/issue6294).  I'm still hoping for an answer on how to eliminate the exception itself, though...

Answer (score 1):

for me a simple `shelve.close()` on an unclosed one did the job.

shelve.open('somefile') returns a "persistent dictionary for reading and writing" object which i used throughout the app's runtime. 
when I terminated the app I received the "TypeError" Exception as mentioned. 
I plased a 'close()' call in my termination sequence and that seemed to fix the problem.

e.g. 
shelveObj = shelve.open('fileName')
...
shelveObj.close()

Comment: Would you mind extending the answer bit more for fellow programmers, to understand how it helps to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

### [OverByThere commented on Jul 17, 2018](https://github.com/ayufan-rock64/linux-build/issues/136#issuecomment-405592727)

[This seems to be fixable.](https://forum.openmediavault.org/index.php/Thread/19658-Upgrade-Debian-9-and-4-x/?postID=164703#post164703)

In short open /usr/lib/python3.5/weakref.py and change line 109 to:

```
 def remove(wr, selfref=ref(self), _atomic_removal=_remove_dead_weakref):
```

And line 117 to:

```
_atomic_removal(d, wr.key)
```

Note you need to do this with spaces, not tabs as this will cause other errors.