# TypeError when using shelve with django

Tags: python, django, shelve

I put this code in the `models.py` of my django application:

```
import shelve
s = shelve.open('mystorage')
```

Everything works right, but when the interpreter is being shutdown, I get the following output:

```
Exception TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable" in  ignored
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Really weird issue with shelve (python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180946/really-weird-issue-with-shelve-python)

Comment: I thought it was before asking the question, but solution the anwser there was about the bug in

Comment: Yes, it's a bug in Pytohn. But there is a workaround in the end of the answer there. Does it work for you?

Comment: the solution there involves closing the file. but in my case I need a file to stay opened until interpreter shuts down. But now I've noticed another answer, which mentions `atexit.register`, and it worked. I'm wondering why this bug is still in 2.6.6, if it was  fixed in 2.6.4 (according to http://bugs.python.org/issue7835)